# Showing up collapsible table exactly in center of the table header

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to show my table header in the center of the web browser page. On pressing the `+` button the data is shown but it is aligned exactly below the table header. I want the collapsible table to be shown exactly in center of the table header. I tried changing in CSS but its not working out. Can anyone kindly help me out?

```js
$('.header').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('expand').nextUntil('tr.header').slideToggle(100);
});
```

```css
table,
tr,
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

tr.header {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.header .sign:after {
  content: "+";
  display: inline-block;
}

.header.expand .sign:after {
  content: "-";
}

table {
  margin-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="0">
  <tr class="header expand">
    <th>Header Header Header Header <span class="sign"></span></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT 1**
Look at the new live demo (based on comments and question change):
https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-e9cazg

```
    <table border="0" style="width: 96%; margin: 0 auto;">
        <tr class="header expand">
            <th>My Table Header Centered <span class="sign"></span></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table style="width: 96%; margin: 0 auto;">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Col 1</th>
                        <th>Col 2</th>
                        <th>Col 3</th>
                        <th>Col 4</th>
                        <th>Col 5</th>
                        <th>Col 6</th>
                        <th>Col 7</th>
                        <th>Col 8</th>
                        <th>Col 9</th>
                        <th>Col 10</th>
                        <th>Col 11</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>data</td>
                        <td>data</td>
                        <td>data</td>
                        <td>data</td>
                        <td>data</td>
                        <td>data</td>
                        <td>data</td>
                        <td>data</td>
                        <td>data</td>
                        <td>data</td>
                        <td>data</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

---

I changed the style in the html table, take a look at this live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-n8yy6k

```
<table border="0" style="width: 96%; margin: 0 auto;">
    <tr class="header expand">
        <th colspan="11">Header <span class="sign"></span></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I hope it's helpful.

Comment: Its working fine..but there is more data in table header to show up in real code..In that case when I press + ,the collapsible table is shown in proper format but table header gets shortened up to almost 50% of the original size.

Comment: A simple solution is to use a table within a table. The header in the first table, the data in the second. Remove the colspan in the header, and in the second tr add the table with the data.

Comment: I saw the edit of the question I think the problem is only the absence of the colspan at this point.

Comment: I am actually trying to add div just after table header to distinguish table header and the table content.But its not working it seems

Comment: I changed the answer with a new live demo

Comment: Please, can you mark the answer as accepted, if that's okay with you (the gray mark next to my answer, under the vote)? Thanks